# Warning: Attempt to present UIImagePickerController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have 3 `ViewControllers`, In my second `ViewController` I have `Dropbox` `Webview` which request files from users. But when i click the button to choose the file it automatically jumps to the previous view controller.

Other case - The `WebView` is working fine, because when I set the 2nd `ViewController` (as initial `ViewController` in `IB`), then it picks images and works fine but when I set main `ViewController` to another VC then push through that VC to `ViewController2` then it jumps automatically to previous `ViewController`.

here is my web view code -

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let URL = NSURL(string: "https://www.dropbox.com");
    Box.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: URL! as URL) as URLRequest)
}
```